SARIMAX Model In-Sample Predictions for different Exog Variable
I am working with a SARIMAX model trained on a given dataset. I am trying to get an in-sample forecast but using different values for exog variables. This is to test how the forecast changes with respect to the actual values if the exog variable is changed. Here is a minimal reproducible code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from io import BytesIO

# Dataset
friedman2 = requests.get('https://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/friedman2.dta').content
data = pd.read_stata(BytesIO(friedman2))
data.index = data.time
data.index.freq = "QS-OCT"

# Variables
endog = data.loc['1959':'1981', 'consump']
exog = sm.add_constant(data.loc['1959':'1981', 'm2'])

# Fit the model
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog, exog, order=(1,0,1))
res = mod.fit(disp=False)

# Create changed exog variables for in-sample dates
exog_test1 = exog.loc['1980-10-01':'1981-10-01']
exog_test1.loc[:, 'm2'] = 1000
exog_test2 = exog.loc['1980-10-01':'1981-10-01']

# Compare predictions with actuals
display(endog.tail())
display(res.fittedvalues['1980-10-01':'1981-10-01'])
display(res.get_prediction(start='1980-10-01', end='1981-10-01', dynamic=True, exog=exog_test1).predicted_mean)
display(res.get_prediction(start='1980-10-01', end='1981-10-01', dynamic=True, exog=exog_test2).predicted_mean)





I can see from the results that the get_prediction() function does provide an actual forecast starting from 1980-10-01 since the values are different from fittedvalues. However, the forecast is exactly the same for both the exog variables. How can I get a forecast that uses the updated exog values?
